# Mobiscroll Demo

Tags: mobiscroll

I am looking at the demo of MobiScroll and have chosen the following options:

```
Demo Page: Demo
Demo: Time
Display: Modal
Mode: Scroller
```

The demo example shows the resulting HTML I should use as:

```
<input id="i" name="i"  />


<a href="#" id="show" class="btn">Show</a>
<a href="#" id="clear" class="btn">Clear</a>
```

When I use this HTML, the Show and Clear buttons show up on the page and when I click in the input box, the Mobiscroll shows up inline.  In the demo, these buttons appear with the Mobiscroll in a modal dialog.  Do I need to wrap the HTML in a div with a special tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the jQuery Mobile js + css files were required to get the modal popup.  The directions on the site are not clear!  I added the following and presto!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
```